# Python: How to keep a variable in memory such that it can be called from other python scripts?

Tags: python

There is a module named tzwhere in python. When I load it in the tz variable as in:-

```
from tzwhere import tzwhere
tz = tzwhere.tzwhere(shapely=True)
```

The line above takes about 45 seconds to load up and its scope is until that particular python session is stopped. So after this line I can get as many outputs of `tz.tzNameAt(latitude, longitude)` as I want, but the problem is that these outputs are quickly calculated only in that python shell.

I want to make tz variable shareable just like an API, such that if tz variable is called from any python session or even if from any java program using exec command, neither it should take 45 seconds to load up again and nor should it give me `NameError: name 'tz' is not defined`.

Please Help. Thank you very much!!

Comment: @mevius sir, Thank you so much for editing this post. I m a newbie, I don't know how to write it professionally...

Comment: You could write a server program which loads the tz structure, listens for requests, process them and sends replies. The scripts will be clients of that server. However it is non-trivial.

Comment: @PrabhatNagpal Sorry, but you have to wait that long. Pickling the object does not make sense, the data stored in the `tzwhere` object is enormous. That's why it does take that long to load. I will work on @VPfB 's answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could probably use the `pickle` module which can store class instances in files.

Try something like this:

```
 from tzwhere import tzwhere
 tz = tzwhere.tzwhere(shapely=True)

 import pickle

 # Dump the variable tz into file save.p
 pickle.dump( tz, open( "save.p", "wb" ) )
```

To load `tz` from another script just do:

```
import pickle

tz = pickle.load( open( "save.p", "rb" ) )
```

> NOTE: Python 2 ONLY, will use faster version automatically if on Python3
>
> If you are still unhappy with the speed when loading `tz` from another script, there is an accelerated version of `pickle` called `cPickle`
>
> Just do:
>
> ```
> import cPickle as pickle
> ```

For more information goto this link: https://wiki.python.org/moin/UsingPickle

Comment: That moment when you post your answer and somebody else proposed the exact same solution... I should learn to write a little bit faster ^^

Comment: This happens to me quit a lot for some reason.

Comment: @AndreiTumbar Sir I followed your steps but it generates this error:-

File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\shapely\prepared.py", line 88, in __reduce__ <br>
    raise PicklingError("Prepared geometries cannot be pickled.") <br>
_pickle.PicklingError: Prepared geometries cannot be pickled.

Comment: maybe try a different caching module such as `GenericCache`. This however works differently in that the cache will not be stored in a file but rather in the memory. I have not tried this software so it may not work after your script has ended but if you store the `tzwhere` class with `GenericCache.insert ()`, it shouldn't take 45 seconds to run.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot share any python object in memory even after python has closed. You can, however, save the state of the object (if the library does support it, if it doesn't, this solution will not work) with `pickle`. `pickle` is a library that ships with python, and can save the state of most objects to a file.

Here is an example for pickle:

To save the state:

```py
import pickle
obj = [1, 2, 3, 4]
f = open("/path/to/the/file/where/the/data/should/be/stored.pickle", 'wb')  # you do not have to use the suffix '.pickle' however.
pickle.dump(obj, f)
f.close()
```

To retrieve it:

```py
import pickle
f = open("/path/to/the/file/where/the/data/should/be/stored.pickle", 'rb')
obj = pickle.load(f)
f.close()
```

Or for your example, run this thing once:

```py
from tzwhere import tzwhere
import pickle
f = open("/path/to/the/file", 'wb')
pickle.dump(tzwhere.tzwhere(shapely=True))
f.close()
```

And use this to retrieve it:

```py
import pickle
f = open("/path/to/the/file", 'rb')
tz = pickle.load(f)
f.close()
```

Or as a one-liner, so that it doesn't take up that much space:

```py
import pickle;f=open("/path/to/the/file",'rb');tz=pickle.load(f);f.close()
```

I hope that helps,

CodenameLambda

PS: If you want to know how pickle works, just look at [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/pickle.html).

Comment: Sir I followed your steps but it generates this error:-

File "D:\Python\lib\site-packages\shapely\prepared.py", line 88, in __reduce__<br>
    raise PicklingError("Prepared geometries cannot be pickled.")<br>
_pickle.PicklingError: Prepared geometries cannot be pickled.

Comment: @PrabhatNagpal This means, that the library does not support pickling.